# NodeJs timezone differs Linux timezone

Tags: node.js, linux, datetime, centos, timezone

I have a Linux server (CentOs to be specific) with npm installed. The server's timezone was UTC and I changed it to IRAN (+4:30).

Now my linux timezone is IRAN (say 7:00 PM) while my node `Date()` returns UTC (4:30 PM).

How can I change the default timezone of Node entirely (and not on a running applications)? I searched a lot and every answer I found was targetting node apps, not the node service in general. I want Node's timezone changed, not the app.

:( by the way, my CentOs does not have any GUI. Answers in text mode are welcome

Comment: I changed the TZ envirnoment variable, the node TimeZone is set, but in pm2 my apps are still showing UTC TimeZone

Comment: Since you didn't show any code, it's nearly impossible to address the point made in your previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by trying different approaches.

First I changed the Timezone of Centos, and my application on pm2 was still on UTC timezone.

Then I changed the TZ var using `cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/...` and still no result.

Then I restarted my CentOs server excpecting the changes to take effect, but no result yet. After server was up, and pm2 reloaded my application, it was still using UTC timezone.

Finally I deleted my application from pm2, and then added it again. That was when my application started using the local timezone.

So keep in mind that no matter what you do to the "Linux TimeZone" or "TZ var", pm2 remembers the timezone of the moment you add your application, and keeps that somewhere and uses that as the timezone of your application.